# Automatically update chromedriver in Visual Studio using WebDriverManager

Tags: vb.net, selenium-webdriver

I am developing a program in Visual Studio using VB.Net. I am trying to access a site using Selenium. I installed the following packages in Nuget:

```
    Selenium.Support
    Selenium.WebDriver
    Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver
    WebDriverManager
```

It normally works, but when Google Chrome updates, the  chromedriver doesn't, even with the WebDriverManager package installed. This is my code:

```
    Imports OpenQA.Selenium
    Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome
    Imports System.Threading
    Imports WebDriverManager.DriverConfigs.Impl
    Imports WebDriverManager

    Module AcessWebsite

        Sub DownloadFile()

            Dim options As New ChromeOptions()
            Dim driverManager = New DriverManager()
            Dim driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "chromedriver.exe")
            driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = True
            driverManager.SetUpDriver(New ChromeConfig())
            Dim driver As New ChromeDriver(driverService, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120))

            'code continuation...

        End Sub

    End Module
```

This code was supposed to update the chromedriver, but when I run it, it gives me this error: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 119
Current browser version is 121.0.6167.86 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe (SessionNotCreated)'

I am using System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "chromedriver.exe" because if I keep ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService() empty, it gives me another error: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchDriverException: 'Unable to obtain chrome using Selenium Manager; For documentation on this error, please visit: [https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location'](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location%27)

What am I doing wrong?